# Why is the text next to the icon in my sidebar nav list moving to the next line when the sidebar is minimized?

Tags: html, css, alignment, sidebar

I am having trouble with my sidebar functionality. Whenever I click the sidebar-toggle button the text of the `<li><a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-address-book"></i> Contacts</a></li>` element moves to the next line even though I have `overflow-y: hidden;` in my stylesheet. Can anyone point out what I'm missing. much appreciated!

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-address-book"></i> Contacts</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="sidebar-toggle">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Bootstrap container -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>TEST CONTENT</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Side-bar toggle script -->
    <script>
      $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function (e) {
        console.log("Hello");
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("side-bar-minimized");
        $("#sidebar-toggle i").toggleClass("fa-angle-left fa-angle-right");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 190px;
}

#wrapper.side-bar-minimized #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 50px;
}

#wrapper.side-bar-minimized #page-content-wrapper {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 8px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: #16a085;
}
```

I have tried splitting the li items into separate elements, fiddled with the css but cannot figure it out.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all I want is for the sidebar-wrapper div to shrink over the text and only show the icon. If this is a stupid way of doing it please do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to solve your problem, is to hide that text on minimized sidebar.
First wrap that text with span, and then add class to hide that span on minimized.

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> <span>Contacts</span></a>
```

Then add this to css

```
  #wrapper.side-bar-minimized .sidebar-nav li a > span {
display: none;  }
```

">" in css is pseudo class, it targets first level child. And use more classes in html for css instead of id's.

Comment: Simple and easy to understand. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot to mention that all I want is for the sidebar-wrapper div to shrink over the text and only show the icon. If this is a stupid way of doing it please do let me know

No it's not stupid way.

What you asked requires you to set fixed width for .sidebar-nav. For example add: width:200px; or maybe better: white-space: nowrap;  So in your case:

```
.sidebar-nav { 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none; 
 width:200px; // or white-space: nowrap;

}
```

And add width to that icon to be exact like shirked sidebar. Like this:

```
.sidebar-nav li a i {
  width:50px;
}
```

This is the simplest way.